# Using nested_form gem for in Rails, undefined method "link_to_remove/add"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, rubygems

I'm trying to use the nested_form gem and I'm experiencing some problems:

**The exact error:** `undefined method link_to_remove for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0xb57e288>`

Here is my **new.html.erb:**

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, 'nested_form' %>
 <div class="recipe new">
   <h2>Add a new recipe</h2>

   <%= nested_form_for(:recipe, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>

     <%= render(:partial => "form", :locals => {:f => f}) %>

     <br />
     <br />
     <div class="form-buttons">
       <%= submit_tag("Create Recipe") %>
     </div>

   <% end %>
 </div>
```

And here is the partial form, **_form.html.erb**:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, 'nested_form' %>

<h3>Recipe Name</h3>
    <%= f.text_field(:recipe_name) %>

<%= fields_for :ingredient do |i| %>
<table summary="Ingredient form fields">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Ingredient</th>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Measurement Unit</td>
    <td>Total Calories</td> 
    <td>Total Grams</td>       
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <%= i.link_to_remove "Remove this ingredient" %>
     <td><%= fields_for :food do |r| %> <%= r.text_field(:long_desc) %><% end %></td>
     <td><%= i.text_field(:quantity, :size => '6', :maxlength => '6') %></td>
     <td><%= i.text_field(:units, :size => '20', :maxlength => '20') %></td>

  </tr>
<% end %>
 <%= i.link_to_add "Add an ingredient" %>

  <tr>

    <td><%= f.text_field(:total_grams, :size => '4', :maxlength => '4') %></td>    
    <td><%= f.text_field(:carb_calories, :size => '4', :maxlength => '4') %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:fat_calories, :size => '4', :maxlength => '4') %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:protein_calories, :size => '4', :maxlength => '4') %></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the **recipe.rb model**:

```
  class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :foods, :through => :recipe_ingredient
  has_many :recipe_ingredient

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_ingredient
  attr_accessible :recipe_name, :prep_time_mins, :total_grams, :carb_calories, :fat_calories, :protein_calories
  attr_accessible :recipe_ingredient_attributes

 end
```

And here is the **recipe_ingredients.rb model:**

```
# join table between each individual food item and their individual nutritional data 
class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :recipe
    belongs_to :food, :foreign_key => 'ndb_no'

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :food
    attr_accessible :food_attributes, :quantity, :units
end
```

Can someone give me some pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by bringing the call to link_to_remove back into the new.html.erb file. It seems it doesn't work if the call is in a partial. Not sure how to get around this though.

Update: I think I found a way to get around it. You can render the partial like so:

```
<%= f.fields_for :tasks %>
```

Doing it this way seems to make a difference. I got this from the README on github's page for nested_form (the section on Partials)

Comment: I am calling the method in the view and still getting the no method error